# Google SmartLock: using the token from an hint to do a Google sign in?

Tags: android, token, google-signin, hint, google-smartlockpasswords

I'm adding Google SmartLock to an existing app and I'm confused about the 
[Sign In Using ID Tokens](https://developers.google.com/identity/smartlock-passwords/android/idtoken-auth). I get the token but I can't use it in the normal login flow. And it doesn't match what I get from a call to Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInResultFromIntent. What I'd like to do is use the hint token to perform a Google sign in. Is the hint token supposed to be used this way or did I miss something?

Thanks

Comment: Good observation, we have been thinking about this: the technical reason that the token is not the same as Google Sign-In is that the Smart Lock API does not require OAuth registration with Google (and we may be able to supply ID tokens for non-Google email addresses). But that said, if you accept Google Sign-In ID tokens already, it would be convenient to get one of the same format, so we are looking into adding that. Any more details on your use case? You can send me an email directly with info: sso@google.com

Comment: At first I was testing whether we should use the hint to perform a Google Sign In (with the token) or just use the hint data to pre-fill the sign in/up form (name, email...). We chose the later as it makes more sense in the current flow of the app. So we will do without the hint token in the end.